# telephonyManager.subscriberId is null

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to get mobile Data Usage between two dates for that i tried to fetch 'subscriberId' from the below code.. but it always returning null

```
open fun getSubscriberId(): String? {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val telephonyManager =
                this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
            telephonyManager.subscriberId
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
```

i want to know the alternative solution for this code

Comment: What Android version do you use for testing? As you can see from the code subscriberId is only available on Android below 10. On newer Android versions this value is not accessible anymore.

Comment: i tried in 10 also as i gone through the blogs but was still failed to fetch the SubscriberID, higher than 10 it got deprecated.. can i have alternative solution for this